# RESTful API Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, restful-url

I'm playing with Ruby on Rails for the first time, and have an app up and running. Here's the quick database definition:

```
Teams
- id: int
- name: char[20]

Answers
- id: int
- answer_value: text
```

I want to be able to type: "http://localhost:3000/teams/1/answers/purple" in a browser
if team 1 answers purple.

I thought that adding the following to my routes.rb file would allow me to do that, but it hasn't.

```
resources :teams do
  resources :answers
  post 'answer_value', :on => :member
end
```

I can see the first answer by team 1 by going to "http://localhost:3000/teams/1/answers/1" , but I don't know how to actually set values via the URI.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, in you answers controller's show action, instead of doing `Answer.find(params[:id])`, do `Answer.find_by_answer_value(params[:id])`

Comment: I think we're getting close with this answer.  I didn't realize that the function that accepts the URL I used in my original question was the show action in the answers controller.  I believe I need to change that to Answer.new(params[:id]) though, not Answer.find_by_answer_value.  I'm not looking up a previous answer, I'm trying to create another one.  Now, I'm running into 'undefined method `stringify_answers' for "<value I entered on URL>":String'... Where do I find the correct way to call new?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm trying to set the value with the URL, not look up a previously created answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an answer, please post to

/teams/1/answers

with parameter :answer => { :answer_value => 'purple' }

Don't append answer_value to the url, looks like it's record id.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Is there no way to set up Ruby on Rails to expect the answer_value on the url instead of the record ID?

Comment: Of course there is. But I do suggest you follow the rails way, with gems like inherit_resources you don't even need to write any code in the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either over ride the `to_param` method in the model, which can do what you are looking for although there are some caveats - including needing to use what @Chirantan suggested with `Answer.find_by_answer_value(params[:id])` for all your finders. You can find more info in this [Railscast on the subject](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) or search for `to_param` in the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and select the entry under ActiveRecord::Integration.

Alternatively you can go with a gem like [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) which provides some more comprehensive functionality and control over the URL construction.

Answer (score 0):

Typing things into your browser won't perform a post, regardless of what you put in the routes, it will only perform a get.
Creating something by a get is not RESTful, and you really shouldn't do it.  That said, since you say you're just 'playing around with rails', you could do this:

If you want a get to create the thing, you have to set it that way in the routes. /teams/1/answers/purple

```
get '/teams/:team_id/answers/:answer_value' => 'answers#create'
```

then in your answers controller, create action, you could just check for a params[:team_id]  and params[:answer value] and make sure that gets set before the save.

```
def create
  @answer = Answer.new()
  @answer.team_id=params[:team_id]
  @answer.answer_value=params[:answer_value]


  respond_to do |format|
    if @answer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @answer, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @answer, status: :created, location: @answer }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```